# Using jQuery to automatically add class to image links in WordPress database

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I'm having to switch lightbox scripts because the one I'm using isn't responsive and the site is moving to a responsive layout. A lot of the site is in WordPress and the script I'm switching to doesn't have a WordPress plugin. I figure all I really need to do is to use jQuery to insert a class into image links when they link to another image. The rest I can take care of in the header.php file. The amount of Javascript I know can be written on the back of a postage stamp, so I'd be very grateful if someone could please tell me if this will work (or if there's a better way of doing it)?

If I add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.js"></script>
```

to the header plus a link to a .js file containing the following code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("a[href$='jpg'] img, a[href$='JPG'] img, a[href$='jpeg'] img, a[href$='JPEG'] img, a[href$='png'] img, a[href$='PNG'] img, a[href$='gif'] img, a[href$='GIF'] img").parent().addClass("theClass");

});
```

will it do the job? I don't have a way of testing this except on the live site so I'd like to get it right first time if possible.

Comment: jQuery is most likely already include in `wp_enqueue_scripts` so might want to leave the CDN for jquery out

Comment: Thank you! I looked for `wp_enqueue_scripts` in functions.php but couldn't find it. This site runs on a child theme of TwentyTen. Is it likely too old for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do all that pattern matching. If you want to add a class to any images that are links, try:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  // Add the class to the image
  jQuery( 'a > img' ).addClass( 'newClass' );
  // or add the class to the link
  jQuery( 'a > img' ).parent().addClass( 'newClass' ); 
} );
```

This would only affect images wrapped in a link tag, but wouldn't affect any other links, PDFs, etc.

**Update**

To target links where the href is an image, you can use something like this (add or change the extensions as needed):

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  jQuery( 'a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"]' ).addClass( 'newClass' );
} );
```

Comment: OK. Now this makes more sense to me. Just one thing. It doesn't seem to specify image links that link to images. Just images which are enclosed by links. Is that right? I need to specifically target image links that link to images - ie. where the href URL is the full size image to the thumbnail image being linked - as I don't want to include images that link to eg. other pages or sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('a').filter(function(){
            return this.href && this.href.match(/\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|a?png)$/i);
        }).find('img').addClass('the-class');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This will search every link and filter out the ones not pointing to an image, then applies a class to the image (avoid classes with capitals, use dashes `-`).
The match is case-insensitive, so, it will match `a.JpG` as well as `a.jpg`.
The file extentions it matches are `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, `apng`, `gif` and `bmp`.
More can be added inside the parenthesis, separated by `|`.

If you want to apply to the link the famous class, remove `.find('img')`.

Now, why am I using `this.href && this.href.match()` instead of using the selector `a[href]`?
This is simply for a performance reason: to lighten the parsing on the selector, so it can use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`. The check `this.href` would be made anyway, but in an earlier stage, but the engine used to match elements would have to work a bit harder.

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand this right, the class is applied to the image? I need the class applied to the <a href="">, not to the thumbnail image and it can only apply where the link to an image is also an image because there are some images linked to posts as well. I didn't quite understand your last sentence?

Comment: @Caldoverde From what I understood in your code, it is selecting the image and applying the class to the image (which is what `a[href$='jpg'] img` is selecting). But as I said, simply remove the part where it says `.find('img')`. And what part you don't understand?

Comment: OK. Well now I'm confused because I lifted the script from a WordPress plugin which injects a class into the image link, because that's how that script works. But you're saying the script I quoted would assign the class to the image not the link?

As for the last sentence, I understand you now. The 'famous class' was throwing me and I couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: @Caldoverde Sorry about that. But yes, the script applies the class to the image and not to the link. Try `jQuery('a[href$="jpg"] img')` in your browser console and you will see an array full of `<img>`s.

Comment: Really? The code snippet you quote just says "where a .jpg image link is linked to an image, doesn't it? The important bit is the bit at the end which says `.parent().addClass("classname")` and that's telling the script to add the class to the parent element, ie. the link, isn't it? If not, then I need to go back and relearn everything on my postage stamp.

Comment: Oh I only just saw your edit! Thanks for the explanation which I understand the sense of even if the Javascript is still a bit beyond me. When you use `this.href && this.href.match()` does it mean that the 2 image URLs have to pretty much match (eg. a-photo.jpg and a-photo_tmb.jpg) or does the match command just compare file extensions?

Comment: @Caldoverde No, when I use `this.href && this.href.match(...)` I'm checking if the `<a>` tag has a `href` and if the `href` is pointing to an image. It simply checks the file extension. It can't check if the image really exists.